# Missing a bolt to take out to remove alternator 2001 Nissan sentra

Tags: nissan, alternator

I am trying to remove the alternator from my 2001 Nissan Sentra. I have taken the belt off, have taken a screw out of each the left and right side (looking from the front of the car).

It seems like at least one more screw probably needs to come out... I cannot tell where it is. Here is visual of what I am talking about: https://youtu.be/Gu5IC0Mg9bU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a long bolt underneath that the alternator pivots on to adjust drive belt tension.

If you are sure you have this out, the alternator is simply cocked on the mounting ears and jammed.  It may take some wiggling and ***gentle persuasion***.